# Proof about binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, approximation

I today see a approximated equation, when $n \ll u $:

$$\log {u \choose n} \approx n \Big(\log \frac{u}{n} + 1.44\Big)$$

I would like to know how to prove it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas

Comment: Use Stirling's approximation for $n!$.

Comment: @JohnBentin No, I mean n is smaller than u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like pedja has pointed you in the right direction here.  On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas) there's the bounds:
\begin{align*}
{u \choose n} &= \frac{1}{n!} u(u-1)\cdots(u-n+1) \\
 & \leq \frac{u^n}{n!} \\
 & \leq \left(\frac{u\ e}{n}\right)^n
\end{align*}
since $n! \geq \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$, and
\begin{align*}
{u \choose n} & = \frac{u}{n} \cdot \frac{u-1}{n-1} \cdots \frac{u-n+1}{1} \\
 & \geq \left(\frac{u}{n}\right)^n.
\end{align*}

By taking $\log_2$ of both sides of these bounds, we obtain \[n \log_2 \frac{u}{n} \leq \log_2 {u \choose n} \leq n \left(\log_2 \frac{u}{n}+\log_2 e\right),\] where $\log_2 e$ is approximately $1.44$.

If $n=o(\log u)$, then \[\log_2 {u \choose n} \sim n \log_2 \frac{u}{n},\] so the $1.44$ won't be necessary.